Understanding rocksdb statistics
I am storing key-value pairs in two ways on rocksdb using their Java API and comparing their stats to see which gives better results. These are the two approaches that I have followed-
version 1
public void createKeyValuePairs(JsonObject obj, boolean isParent, String id) {
        if (isParent) {
            save(defaultCf, id, obj.toString());
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> ele : obj.entrySet()) {
            if (!ele.getKey().equals("id")) {
                String key = id.concat(".").concat(ele.getKey());
                if (ele.getValue().isJsonObject()) {
                    //createKeyValuePairs(ele.getValue().getAsJsonObject(), false, key);
                } else {
                    save(defaultCf, key, ele.getValue().toString());
                }

                if (ele.getKey().equals("created_at")) {
                    String time = String.valueOf(CommonUtils.dateAsId(ele.getValue().getAsString()));
                    String associatedId = id.split("\\.")[0];
                    try {
                        String value = (db.get(timestampIndexCf, time.getBytes()) != null) ? new String(db.get(timestampIndexCf, time.getBytes())) : null;
                        Set<String> idsArr = (value != null) ? new HashSet<>(Set.of(value.split(","))) : new HashSet<>();
                        idsArr.add(associatedId);
                        save(timestampIndexCf, time, String.join(",", idsArr));
                    } catch (RocksDBException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

version 2
public void createKeyValuePairs_v2(JsonObject obj, boolean isParent, String id) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> ele : obj.entrySet()) {
            if (!ele.getKey().equals("id")) {
                String key = "";
                if (ele.getKey().equals("created_at")) {
                    String time = String.valueOf(CommonUtils.dateAsId(ele.getValue().toString().replaceAll("\"", "")));
                    key = ele.getKey().concat(".").concat(time.replaceAll("\"", "")).concat(".").concat(id);
                } else {
                    key = ele.getKey().concat(".").concat(ele.getValue().toString().replaceAll("\"", "")).concat(".").concat(id);
                }

                if (ele.getValue().isJsonObject()) {
                    //do nothing for now
                    //createKeyValuePairs(ele.getValue().getAsJsonObject(), false, key);
                } else {
                    save(defaultCf, key, obj.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

common method to save data to store:
private void save(ColumnFamilyHandle handle, String key, String value) {
        try {
            db.put(handle, key.getBytes(), value.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Object saved! " + key + " :: " + value);
        } catch (RocksDBException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to save");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

I'm using a single line of code stats.toString() to display the stats for both methods, but I fail to understand the data that I see.
For the property rocksdb.block.cache.miss COUNT I get a 0 for version 1, but 578015 for version 2. This seems wrong to me, because no db.get (read) call happens in version 2, so there should be no cache hits or misses. Also rocksdb.number.keys.read COUNT  and rocksdb.bytes.read COUNT  is 0 for version 2, then why are there so many cache misses?
Secondly, I see some numbers for rocksdb.memtable.hit COUNT and rocksdb.memtable.hit COUNT  for version 1. Shouldn't the cache be accessed first for the read? So there should be something in cache miss count, definitely not 0.
I could not find any sources explaining any results, I would appreciate any help/links in understanding these.
